# SQL Server : Backup Error

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, backup

When we are trying to backup our database we get an error.

```
Front End         : VB.Net
Back End          : SQL Server
DB Name           : PROFITSTORAGE
Backup Location   : 'D:\Profit\Data\ProfitStorage.Bak'
```

Code:
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim query As SqlCommand

```
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Server=(LocalHost);Data Source=LocalHost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI"
        con.Open()
        query = con.CreateCommand
        query.CommandText = "BACKUP DATABASE PROFITSTORAGE TO DISK='D:\Profit\Data\ProfitStorage.bak' WITH INIT"
        query.ExecuteNonQuery()
        query.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Backup Failed")
    End Try
```

Query used :

```
BACKUP DATABASE PROFITSTORAGE 
TO DISK='D:\Profit\Data\ProfitStorage.bak' WITH INIT
```

Error Message :

> Cannot open backup device 'D:\Profit\Data\ProfitStorage.bak'. Operating system error 3 (failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

How to sort out this issue?

Comment: Error #3 is : **The system cannot find the path specified.** - you're using a path that doesn't exist on that machine where SQL Server is running. The backup will be created **on the machine** where SQL Server is running - ***not*** on your local machine. Is that the trouble maybe? Does the machine where SQL Server is running even have a `D:\` drive??

Comment: It says `LocalHost` so I'll guess it's on the same machine where the program is running... but I too believe there's no `D:\Profit\Data` directory on that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is not creating the folder if its not existing.

 We should create a folder manually instead.

Since we are using VB.Net we had to create a folder with the following code before backup:

```
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("D:\Profit\Data\")
```